# Django recommended structure TastyPie

Tags: django

Using [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/) (API framework for Django) what is the recommended file structure (or in your opinion).

Have a different resources in each app something like this:

```
app1
   models.py
   resources.py

app2
   models.py
   resources.py
```

Or create a new app say and have one resource one resource:

```
app1
app2
apiApp
  resources.py
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is very simple and efficient structure of tastypie api.**

```
Projectname    
    app1
        api
            __init__.py
            resource.py
        models
            __init__.py
            model1.py
            model2.py
        migrations
            __init__.py
        __init__.py

    app2
        api
        models
        migrations
        __init__.py

    common
        __init__.py
        constant.py
        authentication.py
        commondata.py

    middleware
        __init__.pt
        cors.py

    projectname
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    manage.py
    Projectname.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new app for just resources does not make sense. I would go with having different resources in each app. Alternatively you can have them in /resource.